# Solving system of 2 equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have to solve this system of equations of three unknowns.

10x+5y+0.5z = 100
x+y+z = 100

In my course I was told to use a `for` loop, but, in my opinion, that was is difficult. I think, I can use numpy, but my code is incorrect.

```py
import numpy as np

M1 = np.array([[10., 5., 0.5], [1., 1., 1.]])                        
v1 = np.array([100., 100.])

np.linalg.inv(M1).dot(v1)
```

Comment: To solve for 3 unknowns in general, you need 3 equations, and you have only 2

Answer (score 4):

When solving multi-variable linear equations with less equations than variables, this becomes difficult. This is because the solution is not unique. This means that there are multiple answers for the same group of equations. If your question includes a third equation, the code to solve that group of equations would look like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3]] # Matrix of the coefficients of the left hand side of the equ.
B = [[d1],[d2],[d3]] # Where the d's represents the coefficients of the right hand side of the equ.
C = np.linalg.solve(A,B) # The order of the A,B matter.
#Also pay attention to the dimension of the matrices A = (3,3) , B = (3,1)
#If we had to swap the dimension of B = [d1,d2,d3] = (1,3) this calculation would 
#not work.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is an underconstrained problem, which means there are infinitely many solutions, as other people have stated. One option for solving such a problem is to use Tikhonov regularization, aka [ridge regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression). Your current problem is `Ax = b` where `A` is a `2x3` matrix, `x` is a `3x1` vector, and `b` is a `2x1` vector. Tikhonov regularization says you can find the vector `x` with the smallest 2-norm by solving this problem instead: `(A'A - λI)x = A'b` and then taking the limit as `λ` goes to 0.

Here is the problem solved in sympy.

```py
import sympy as smp

A = smp.Matrix([[10, 5, smp.Rational(1,2)], [1, 1, 1]])
b = smp.Matrix([[100], [100]])
lamb = smp.symbols("\\lambda")
x = (A.T@A - lamb*smp.eye(3)).solve(A.T@b).subs(lamb, 0)
print(x)  # Matrix([[-3050/271], [9450/271], [20700/271]])
```

We can check that our solution works.

```py
print(A@x) # Matrix([[100], [100]])
```

Again, this is just *a* solution when there are actually infinitely many. Another option is to assume you know one of the variables and then solve for the other two in terms of that third one. For example, assume we know `x`, we can solve for `y` and `z` in terms of `x`.

```py
import sympy as smp

x, y, z = smp.symbols("x y z")

eq1 = smp.Eq(10*x + 5*y + smp.Rational(1,2)*z, 100)
eq2 = smp.Eq(x + y + z, 100)

sol = smp.solve([eq1, eq2], [y, z])
print(sol) # {y: 100/9 - 19*x/9, z: 10*x/9 + 800/9}
```