# sympy solve one equation in 2 unknowns and symbols

Tags: sympy, equation, solver, equation-solving

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a, b
```

I want to find the roots in x and y for the following equation: f(x,y) = 2(x - a) + (y - b), whose roots are x=a, y=b. Using sympy I get instead

`sym.solve((x - a)*2 + (y - b), [x, y])`

$\left[ \left( a + \frac{b}{2} - \frac{y}{2}, y\right)\right]$

In other words, sympy treats y as a symbol (or scalar) instead of variable even if I ask it to solve for y as well. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving system of 2 equations with 3 unknowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926345/solving-system-of-2-equations-with-3-unknowns)

Comment: it does help, but from another perspective. The question was actually about using sympy to solve this issue, but as there was another one due to the use of an underdetermined system, I think it is slightly less on the point than the others. My bad for the imprecision in any case

Comment: @jared alternatively I can also edit the question with another example. It is the same for me

Comment: Did you read my answer on the proposed duplicate? I used sympy.

Comment: @jared you are right, I did not actually see it as I stopped at the other answer. This is probably the most fitting answer

Comment: Which, the one on your question or the duplicate? If the duplicate, then you should mark this question as such.

Comment: Marked as duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots you have there are not the only possible roots. Looking at your

2(x - a) + (y - b)

formula, if we equate it to 0 to find the roots:

2(x - a) + (y - b) = 0

then it's clear that

x = (2a + b - y) / 2

and

y = b - 2(x - a)

so there are infinitely many possible roots. besides the roots you have given (x=a, y=b) we could define other roots, like (x = b/2 and y = 2a), having

2(b/2 - a) + 2a - b = 0

b - 2a + 2a - b = 0

0 = 0

as the result and infinitely many possible cases, you take an arbitrary x and compute its corresponding y or take an arbitrary y and compute its corresponding x to generate as many possible root pairs as you like. This is why finding the roots will not lead you to a single tuple, but infinitely many ones.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I was blinded by the Python problem to recognize that this is, trivially, an underdetermined system of equations. Hence there is actually no problem at all, because what I am asking is just not there

Comment: @user9875321__ happy to help. If this answer helped you settle the issue, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`SymPy` is treating `y` as a constant instead of a variable in the equation. To overcome this issue and find the roots for both `x` and `y`, you can use one of the following approaches:

Solve for `x` in terms of `y` and then substitute it back into the original equation to solve for `y`:

```
from sympy import Eq, solve

x = solve(2*(x - a) + (y - b) == 0, x)[0]
f_substituted = f.subs(x, x)
y = solve(Eq(f_substituted, 0), y)[0]

print("x =", x, ", y =", y)
```

Use sympy's `linsolve` function to directly solve the system of linear equations derived from the original equation:

```
from sympy import Eq, linsolve

# Convert the equation to a system of linear equations
equations = [Eq(2*(x - a) + (y - b), 0)]

# Solve the system for x and y
solution = linsolve(equations, [x, y])

print("x =", solution[x], ", y =", solution[y])
```

Either of these approaches should give you the correct solution: `x = a, y = b`.

Remember to ensure your equation is in the form of `Eq(f(x, y), 0)` before using `linsolve`, and use solve cautiously, especially with multiple variables.

I hope this helps.

Comment: great solutions, but as @Lajos Arpad pointed out below, I took a bad example for this.